# quebra linha dentro da string

Tags: php

Como inserir quebra de linha em uma string, sem aumentar o número de caracteres?

```
    <?php 

        $str = "Vou para Manaus";               
        echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 15

        $str = "Vou para
        Manaus";                
        echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 18


    ?>
```

Comment: Acredito que não seja possivel pois o espaço e contato como caractere, qual e o seu objetivo com isto ?

Comment: @Gabriel, é comum ter esse tipo de regra num modelo de negócio. Exemplo, contar quantos caracteres foram digitados num texto, porém ignorar contagem de espaçamentos, quebras de linha, e pontuações. Num exemplo prático, um serviço de tradução de textos onde o preço da tradução é baseado na quantidade de caracteres. Seria injusto cobrar por espaços e quebras de linha.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, esteja ciente da diferença entre caracteres e bytes.

A função `strlen()` retorna quantidade em bytes.

CAso queira contar a quantidade de caracteres, utilize a função `mb_strlen()`

```
$str = "Vou para Maranhão";
echo strlen($str); //exibe 18
echo mb_strlen($str); //exibe 17
```

Vamos ao ponto principal?

contar a quantidade de caracteres ignorando as quebras de linha:

```
$str = "Vou para 
Maranhão";

$l = mb_strlen( str_replace("
",'',$str) );
echo PHP_EOL . $l; //exibe 17
```

A ideia é simples. Apenas remova os caracteres indesejados antes da contagem.

Brincando um pouco mais, podemos criar uma função:

```
$str = "Vou para 
Maranhão";

/**
No segundo parâmetro, indique os caracteres que dseja ignorar. O argumento recebe `string` ou `array`
*/
function mb_strlen2( $str, $ignore = null )
{
    return mb_strlen( str_replace($ignore,'',$str) );
}

/*
 Ignora quebras de linha
*/
echo PHP_EOL . '<br />' . mb_strlen2( $str, PHP_EOL );

/*
 Ignora quebras de linha e espaçamentos
*/
echo PHP_EOL . '<br />' . mb_strlen2( $str, [ PHP_EOL, ' ' ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```
    <?php 

    $str = "Vou para Manaus";               
    echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 15

    $str = "Vou para \n Manaus";                
    echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 18


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já testou assim:

```
<?php 
        $str = "Vou para Manaus";               
        echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 15
        $str = "Vou para" . PHP_EOL . "Manaus";                
        echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 18
?>
```

Uma constante PHP de quebra de linha que se ajusta de acordo o sistema operacional.

Answer (score -5):

tente assim

```
$str = "Vou para "\n" Manaus";                
echo(strlen($str)); //exibe 18
```

Comment: Você não está concatenando